# Extjs 'Ext.ux.DataView.Draggable' fails on initialization

Tags: extjs, view, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm trying to D-n-D items from View to another View or Panel.

All sources points to [Ext.ux.DataView.Draggable](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ux.DataView.Draggable). But it doesn't work for me.

Following [code from Extjs docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ux.DataView.Draggable) fails:

```
Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
    mixins: {
        draggable: 'Ext.ux.DataView.Draggable'
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        this.mixins.draggable.init(this, {
            ddConfig: {
                ddGroup: 'someGroup'
            }
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

**this.mixins.draggable** set as undefined. So **init** method not found.

Error logs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object Ext.ux.DataView.Draggable has no method 'init'

Ext.create.initComponent fiddle.jshell.net:28
Ext.define.constructor ext-all.js:15
b.callParent ext-all.js:15
Ext.define.constructor ext-all.js:15
Ext.Class.m ext-all.js:15
(anonymous function)
Ext.ClassManager.instantiate ext-all.js:15
(anonymous function) ext-all.js:15
window.onload
```

Is there any simple way to get it worked ?

**Edit1**: [Here you can try it](http://jsfiddle.net/KbqHa/8/) ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have got it and thanks for '*Mitchell Simoens*' who have answered same question on *sencha forum*. In this way I publish his solution, whose I think is well done: [Ext.ux.DataView.Draggable failed to initialization !](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185401-Ext.ux.DataView.Draggable-failed-to-initialization-!)

**Answer in few words:**
You shouldn't override initComponent and set the mixins when using Ext.create, you should do that in Ext.define. [Example](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185401-Ext.ux.DataView.Draggable-failed-to-initialization-!&p=749046&viewfull=1#post749046).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to look at: `Ext.dd.DragZone` - [documentation link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.dd.DragZone). `Ext.ux.DataView.Draggable` does state that it requires it to work, and it does contain your missing init function. Hope that helps.